# Como fazer listas e cartões igual ao Trello

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-recyclerview, trello

Preciso fazer aquelas listas com cartões igual e utilizado pelo Trello, com rolagem para os lados. O que é utilizado para fazer aquilo?

Comment: Acredito que dê para simular aquele efeito, utilizando um recycler view na horizontal, onde a view de cada coluna da recycler é constituida com o cadview e outra lista dentro dela. Somente o efeito de arrastar as coisas que vai ser mais complicado de simular.

Answer (score 0):

Pra criar o cartão é o usado o `CardView`. Veja aqui na documentação [como criar cartões](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=pt-br). 
Pra criar a rolagem lateral é usado um *Swipe Views*. Veja aqui na documentação [as orientações para se criar um *Swipe View*](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode também [criar um Swipe View com Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

Comment: Tem como colocar listas dentro desse swipe? Com cartões?

Comment: @LucasBrugneraMartinelli sim.

Comment: @LucasBrugneraMartinelli conseguiu resolver?! Precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 0):

Para os cartões você utiliza um **CardView** 
Para rolar para o lado, você pode tanto usar uma **ViewPager** OU você pode usar um **ScrollView** com `orientation="horizontal"` , que ai ele vai rolar para o lado

Answer (score -2):

DICA de extensão pro TRELLO

Uso essa extensão para Chrome, que conta cards das colunas e de toda a board.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cardcounter-for-trello-wi/jbdmgabkegidhagemkfdogmplgelaoab